# Need help determining what causes Zypper --no-color option to be ignored

Tags: opensuse, colors, zypper

When I issue `zypper --no-color update -y` I can still see ANSI codes. Here is a sample of the log:

```
Retrieving package glibc-extra-2.31-150300.41.1.x86_64                                                                  (11/460),  64.6 KiB( 27.7 KiB unpacked)
←[2K
Retrieving: glibc-extra-2.31-150300.41.1.x86_64.rpm --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[starting]
←[2K
Retrieving: glibc-extra-2.31-150300.41.1.x86_64.rpm ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[\ (1.1 KiB/s)]
←[2K
Retrieving: glibc-extra-2.31-150300.41.1.x86_64.rpm ..........................................................................................[done (1.1 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package gtk3-data-3.24.34-150400.3.3.1.noarch                                                                (12/460), 111.5 KiB(  7.3 KiB unpacked)
←[2K
```

Remarkably, it contains only the ANSI codes on blank lines. Without the `--no-color` option it would have contained many more of them: at the start and end of each line.

How can I completely get rid of all ANSI codes?

Answer (score 0):

The `zypper` utility should not use *any* ANSI escapes if the terminal is "dumb" (`TERM=dumb`) or the output is redirected to something that is not a terminal.  Unfortunately, it's not clear how you created your "log".  Feel free to update the question with information about this.

In the answer below, I will assume that there is something wrong with your version of `zypper` and that it ignores the fact that it does not write its output to a non-terminal.

---

As the `\033[2K` escape is used for [erasing the current line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) (it's the `EL` or "erase in line" code and it has nothing to do with colour), it's not entirely clear what you want to get as output as just removing the escape would presumably leave characters unerased on the line.

To remove the `\033[2K` escape, use something like

```
e2k=$( printf '\033[2K' )
your command | sed "s/$e2k//g"
```

To empty the lines that have this escape sequence (also removing anything on the line outputted *after* the escape code):

```
e2k=$( printf '\033[2K' )
your command | sed "s/.*$e2k.*//"
```

Since `\033[2K` does not move the cursor, a more sophisticated approach would need to calculate the current cursor position and only clear the line up to that point.

You can [get rid of all ANSI codes](https://stackpointer.io/unix/unix-linux-remove-ansi-escape-sequences/464/), but since some of these are used for things like cursor positioning etc., you would have to specify what you want each code to be replaced with, or you may end up with an even more garbled and incomprehensible text file.  In this case, the only code you appear to be concerned with is the one mentioned in this answer though.